# Russian equivalent for 'Rise and shine?'

Tags: перевод, фраза

Is there a Russian saying that is similar to the English phrase 'rise and shine' when you want to wake someone up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Вставайте, граф, вас ждут великие дела!
- Проснись и пой.

Comment: First one is little bit ironic. At least I use it with irony.

Answer (score 4):

If we talk about "boys", then I can only think of "military-style": *Рота, подъём!*

Answer (score 0):

Also, If you want to parody someone, who can't wake up fast, you can say: "Поднимите мне веки!" (It is citation from [Viy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viy_(story)))